# Is it possible to use Facebook SDK for iOS without published app?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk

I am following this tutorial on Facebook to integrate with the Facebook SDK in iOS:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

It asks me for the IPHONE STORE ID, but my app is not developed yet, so I do not have this ID.

Well, I have this ID, but the app is not yet published and isn't publicly accessible.

Is it possible to integrate with the Facebook SDK without a published app?

Answer (score 0):

For developers or testing, you can add the "0" IPHONE STORE ID.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `SDK` without publishing the APP.

This information is added when you are creating a page for your application or if you are submitting to facebook with more permissions than the default permissions. But even if you want submit is possible to send only the `.ipa` file without the `iPhone Store ID`.